# What is a good 2D scrolling shoot-em-up for iPad in the style of Gradius V

Tags: ipad, software-recommendation, games

I'm looking for a shooter in the style of [Gradius V](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradius_V), meaning futuristic, weapon power ups, frantic action. I'm not interested in a WW1/WW2 style shooter.

Google and the app store are not coming up with any relevant results; any ideas?

Also, iPad specific (can be universal binary of course!), iPad 1 compatible. I have an iPad 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [Space Tripper](http://itunes.apple.com/app/space-tripper/id473164288?mt=8). It's well reviewed on [touchArcade](http://toucharcade.com/2011/11/21/space-tripper-review/).